# Working with CSVs in SSIS without SQL Database connection

Tags: t-sql, ssis

So I am tasked with performing some calculation in SSIS on a CSV file using T-SQL. Once I am complete I need to save the project as an ISPAC file so other users outside my business can run the program too, however their SQL connection managers will obviously differ from mine. To that end is it possible to use T-SQL to make modifications to a CSV inside of SSIS without actually using a connection manager to an SQL database? If so, what tasks would I use to achieve this? Many Thanks

EDIT: For more clarification on what i need to achieve: Basically I am tasked with adding additional data to a CSV file. For example adding forename and surname together etc, create new columns such as month numbers, names etc from a date string then output that to a new CSV location. I am only allowed to use T-SQL and SSIS to achieve this. Once Complete I need to send the SSIS project file to another organisation to use therefore I cannot hardcode any of my connections or assume they hold any of the databases I will use.

My initial question is can all this be done inside of SSIS using T-SQL but I think I have the answer to that now. I plan to parameterise the connection string, source file location, output file and use the Master DB and temp DBs to perform the SQL code to add the additional data, so they will have SQL their end but it wont make any assumptions on what they are using

Comment: _their SQL connection managers will obviously differ from mine_ This is catered for with project parameters and parameterisation of connection managers. Having said that, if you need a portable engine that performs calcs on a CSV file, SSIS is probably not your best option as anyone who wants to run it needs to install SQL Server

Comment: _use T-SQL to make modifications to a CSV inside of SSIS_ Where does this requirement come from? It seems very specific and very convoluted

Comment: Thanks Nick, I'll look into project parameterisation for the connection strings. Happy to do the legwork myself but any links you can provide with helpful information will be much appreciated

Comment: This blog (SQLChick) is consistently high quality and explains things really well https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2015/1/4/parameterizing-connections-and-values-at-runtime-using-ssis-environment-variables

Comment: Thanks, if you want to put this down as an answer instead of a comment I'd be happy to mark it as the answer as this points me in the right direction, thanks

Comment: You mentioned using T-SQL to modify the CSV without actual an database connection, have you looked into doing these modifications with a Script Task or Component?

Comment: @SQL_Kid link-only answers are frowned upon on Stack Overflow.   If the link ever goes dead, the answer will be useless.   The best outcome here would be that if the link helps you solve your problem, you come back and post your own answer describing what you did to solve it, and then mark your answer as the answer so the question and answer can help future readers.

Comment: I agree - my answer is links only so it's not a real answer. The best outcome of this is if you came back and documented what you actually did.

Comment: TBH project parameterisation itself is not really suitable for SO because it's a fundamental part of SSIS and is documented in a number of places... it can just be hard to find without the correct search terms.

Comment: Script tasks are for C# / VB which I do know a bit of, however not enough to modify the data itself. I would be much more comfortable using T-SQL and apparently it's possible to do so I'm just working through it. When I resolve the problem I will post the answer. Thanks for the update guys appreciate it

Comment: I've added more in the descrption